# Single matrix subtraction in a for -sentence

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, for-loop, subtraction

I am totally new python 2.7 user.

My issue is that, I need to make a calculation. 
I have a matrix.

```
A=[1, 2, 8, 10]
```

I want to automate an calculation.

```
A[1]-A[0]=1
A[2]-A[1]=6
```

and so on.

But I can't figure out to do so.
So far I have:

```
for n in xy_list:
    B=n[0][1:]-n[0][:3]
print B
```

The result says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Hope you can help!

Comment: Arrays make life  much easier in such cases where you can simply use roll command and take the difference in a vectorised approach

Comment: Please check below answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you are not understanding iterating through a array/list at all.

If you loop throug the list, you have the list xy_list and an iterator n. `n` in this case is not the array. It's just an index that gets incremented. You'd have to access the list **at** index `n`. So instead of coding `n[0]`, you'd better write `xy_list[n]` which says "the element in xy_list with index n".

If you want to subtract xy_list[0] from xy_list[1] you have to write `B = xy_list[1] - xy_list[0]`

If you want to do that with all elements in the list, you have to code a loop which takes the elemtent on the current index and substracts the element on index `n-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
for n in range(1, len(A)):
    print(A[n] - A[n-1])
```

Here I am assuming that you always want `A[n] - A[n-1]` where n is the integer index in A.

If you want to print it in a *fancy* way:

```
for x in range(1, len(A)):
    print("A[{}] - A[{}]: {}".format(x, x-1, A[x] - A[x-1]))


A[1] - A[0]: 1
A[2] - A[1]: 6
A[3] - A[2]: 2
```